# For concert pass booking form i am trying to create a unique id based on my concert id so that each concert bookings will have a unique id

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
                                                                      Handles btnNew.Click

    bs.AddNew()
    abc = "Select max(Ticket_No) from Concert_Booking order by Concert_Id"
    daaTemp = New OleDbDataAdapter(abc, cn)
    dssTemp.Clear()
    daaTemp.Fill(dssTemp)
    If IsDBNull(dssTemp.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
        txtTicket_No.Text = 1
    Else
        txtTicket_No.Text = dssTemp.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Why don't you set the column to increment automatically on the table itself? That way on every insert it will get a unique Id.

Comment: I am storing all the bookings in one table thats why i require a unique id to differentiate each booking from another. for example my concert id is 17001 then my booking id for that concert should be 17001001 and similarly for other concert suppose concert id is 18001 than the booking id should be 18001001

Comment: Providing a unique ID for each row is the job of the DataBase.  trying to create your own based on `MAX` *will* fail.

Comment: Down votes and non helpful comments guys. Me thinks the real question he is asking, is how do I assign a sequential Ticket-No when adding a record to a database... That is something very different from the AutoNumber record ID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a single seat application,  you are going to have to do some tricks to create a ticket sequence number.

1. First have your database include an autonumber type ID field an use this number internally to your program to reference individual records.
2. Have your table include a Ticket_No field to contain the 1,2,3
3. When first creating a record, leave the Ticket_No as DbNull
4. After creation, reread the table ordered by the autonumberID and scan through that data to find the AutoNumberID you just created keeping track of the ticket count to find it.
5. Once found, set the ticket number on that record to the count.

However, this method only works if YOU DO NOT PHYSICALLY DELETE any records from the database. If you need that functionality, mark them with a field as Cancelled or some such instead.

Once the above is done you can build your concatenated concert_ID-Ticket_ID on the fly for display or printing.

BTW: You may also want to include "Performance_ID" in the ticket no, if whatever the show is runs on more than one day, matinees etc.

**However**

It may be more prudent to pre-assign a block of records for a show rather than creating them at booking time. Pretty much every show has X Number of tickets for sale at different costs depending on seat location, show time/night etc. Searching for seat availability is a function you will probably need one day. Having your program set-up that block of records when you ADD the concert definitions is the more commonly used method.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for help but i tried this and it worked

```
    Private Sub txtConcert_Id_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtConcert_Id.TextChanged

    abc = "Select max(Ticket_No) from Concert_Booking where Concert_Id=" &    txtConcert_Id.Text
    da_new = New OleDbDataAdapter(abc, cn)
    ds_new.Clear()
    bsnew = New BindingSource
    da_new.Fill(ds_new)

    txtTicket_No.Text = ds_new.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) + 1

End Sub
```